# Sample executable hanging after fresh Windows OMNeT++ Installation

Tags: omnet++

I was trying to use OMNeT++ earlier today but I was unable to get any simulation to run. I tried numerous model simulations but they began hanging at the same place during initialization. I deleted and re-installed OMNeT++, but the problem persists. So even after a fresh install of OMNeT++ v5.5.1 on a Windows 10 v1903 machine, I am unable to run any simulation. This is what I saw when I ran the Aloha sample simulation executable directly after following all the OMNeT++ installation steps:

[image]

The Qtenv simulation window starts up but it's completely blank, and I can't actually focus on it, which leads me to believe there's something up with Qt. The program hangs indefinitely at this point. OMNeT++ was configured using the default values found in configure.user.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

This is the last console output I receive after running `QT_LOGGING_RULES="*.debug=true" ./aloha`.
[image: Upon running <code>QT_LOGGING_RULES="debug" ./aloha</code>]

This is the last console output I receive after running `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 ./aloha`.
[image: Upon running <code>QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 ./aloha</code>]

Answer (score 2):

Did you connect additional monitor to your computer? Sometimes Windows remember position of an application on non-existed screen. Try to change your screen properties or connect second screen and look for Qtenv window of Aloha simulation.
Besides the above, delete `.qtenvrc` from `samples/aloha`.

Comment: I have used OMNeT++ in the past with this machine and an additional connected monitor. I just now tried connecting an additional external monitor and running the sample Aloha executable as I did before. Unfortunately, I get the same result. I have added more information to my question regarding what occurs with the Qtenv window when I run one of these sample executables.

Comment: Regarding the deletion of ```.qtenvrc``` from ```samples/aloha```, I do not see this file in the mentioned directory.

Comment: Set `debug-on-errors=true` in `omnetpp.ini` then open IDE and run Aloha in debug mode. The execution will stop just before the line which causes an error (an example [here](https://docs.omnetpp.org/tutorials/tictoc/part2/)).

Comment: Could you check whether you are able to run simulation in command env mode, by typing `./aloha -u Cmdenv -c PureAloha1`

Comment: Setting ```debug-on-errors=true``` in ```omnetpp.ini``` does not give me any extra information unfortunately, i.e. there's no error that is encountered. The program simply hangs.

Comment: Running the simulation in command env mode works! I see the collection of chronological events take place.

Comment: All of the troubleshooting thus far leads me to believe the problem is with Qt

Comment: Yes, there is a problem with QT. The lack of `.qtenvrc` confirms this. Try `echo $PATH` in Mingw console, and check whether there are other QT libraries in this path.

Comment: Something I find interesting is that within ```$PATH```, there is ```/c/omnetpp-5.5.1//bin``` but not ```/c/omnetpp-5.5.1/bin```. I thought perhaps the ```liboppqtenv.dll``` could not be found so I added ```/c/omnetpp-5.5.1/bin``` to ```$PATH```, but it still didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: My full ```$PATH``` now is: ```.:/c/omnetpp-5.5.1//bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/c/Windows/System32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl```. No other Qt library jumps out at me, but I might not be looking in the right away...

Comment: Path looks file. You should figure out whether the Qtenv is running correctly (just not visible). After starting aloha (do not click anywhere with the mouse) press "Enter" then CTRL-q . If the simulation exits, then it was running fine you just was not able to see the window for some reason. (The first Enter select the actual configuration and CTRL-q is the quit keyboard shortcut in Qtenv).

Comment: Starting with
QT_LOGGING_RULES="*.debug=true" ./aloha
or
QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 ./aloha
may give you additional hints...

Comment: @Rudi, I have appended images showing the last of the console output when these commands are run. Does anything jump out to you?

Comment: How frustrating! I didnt realize that this issue came about whenever I disconnected my second monitor until you mentioned it. For a quick fix see [move a lost screen back to your desktop](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/bring-misplaced-off-screen-windows-back-to-your-desktop-keyboard-trick/), courtesy of [Torok](https://groups.google.com/g/omnetpp/c/maXqnTWN970/m/KohFFu57AwAJ)